# Using sessions in a class based view

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to use sessions in a class based view (and have sessions set up as per the docs in apps and middleware).  However I'm not sure if I should be doing this by overidding dispatch.  With the below view I get the

`'ServiceTypeView' object has no attribute 'method'`

View:

```
class ServiceTypeView(CreateView):
    form_class = ServiceTypeForm
    template_name = "standard_form.html"
    success_url = '/'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.session['dummy_data'] = 'initializer'
        return super().dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

(note using python 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the superclass' dispatch method, you shouldn't pass `self` explicitly. It should be:

```
return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```